# how can I grep for a text and display the paragraph

Tags: grep

below text is in a file,

```
Pseudo name=Apple
Code=42B
state=fault

Pseudo name=Prance
Code=43B
state=good
```

need to grep for **42B** from the above file so that the output only should display

```
Pseudo name=Apple
Code=42B
state=fault
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
perl -00ne "print if /Code=42B/i"
```

Answer (score 1):

use before and after modifiers

```
grep -B 1 -A 1 42B file.txt
```

Comment: If that format never changes.. fine. Add another line, change the order of the lines, and it's broken. Add 42B to one of the names.. broken.

Comment: You are right @KarolyHorvath, I just assumed the format stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, only on AIX:

```
grep -p Code=42B file.txt
```